# How to add an add an app icon in ionicframework in ios

Tags: ionic-framework

I have seem a lot of example in how to do it for the android but not ios. I created a iPad application using ionic but have that the little robot icon. I created my own .png icon and I want to use it, but some reason i can't do it. I have used this instruction http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/adding-an-icon/ but they don't seem to work.

So I ask how do it change the application icon ?

Answer (score 3):

The icon image’s minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px, and should have no rounded corners.

Please visit

1. http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html,
2. http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Ionic supply `ionic resources` cli command to generate app icon and splash easily. The only thing you need do is that prepare an icon file in ./resources directory, named icon. The icon file type should be .png, .ai and .psd and should be 192*192px without rounded corners because ionic server would handle rounded corners for you. If you just want to generate icon, use:

```
ionic resources --icon
```

or maybe you want to generate icon and splash, use:

```
ionic resources
```

read more about *Icon and Splash Screen Image Generation*, please refer: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html. Or you could only execute `ionic help resources` in your terminal, then get information you want. Hope this will help you. Regards!